# Inserting snippet using inline R code not working as expected

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, code-snippets

I would like to use snippets in RStudio to insert this bit of code:

```
`r emo::ji("XXX")`
```

I have tried to define this snippet as Markdown (and as R) like this:

```
snippet emo
    `r emo::ji("XXX")`
```

but to no avail. When I try to insert this snippet by typing `emo` and hitting `TAB+Shift` even the word `emo` disappears. RStudio seems not to accept this inline R code as Markdown snippet (unless I am wrong). I was expecting that RStudio replaces `emo` by the code snippet above.

Notes:

- R.3.4.0
- Mac recent OS
- RStudio 1.1.331
- library {emo} attached